# Delegate does not trigger method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates

I've looked at other delegate questions but there weren't any good existing answers. Everything should be set up properly, I can see my slider will change value in logs. For some reason, the delegate function numberOfSquaresInSquareView() never fires when I call it from squareView, and the squareView delegate call just returns nil. I know I am fairly close since this closely matches some lessons I've found, but I think I am missing something. The changeSquareCount() works and I can see in logs that it saves the value.

squareView.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
@class SquareView;
@protocol SquareViewDelegate <NSObject>

- (NSNumber *)numberOfSquaresInSquareView:(SquareView *)squareView;

@end

@interface SquareView : NSView
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SquareViewDelegate> delegate;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

squareView.m

```
#import "SquareView.h"

@implementation SquareView
@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    NSLog(@"drawing rect");
    [[NSColor redColor]set];

    //NSNumber *num = ; //cound pass in nil, dont matter
    NSLog(@"squares to draw: %@", [delegate numberOfSquaresInSquareView:self]);
    // Drawing code here.
}

@end
```

AppController.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SquareView.h"
//@class SquareView;
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface AppController : NSObject <SquareViewDelegate>

@property (retain) IBOutlet SquareView *squareView;

- (IBAction)changeSquareCount:(id)sender;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

AppController.m

```
#import "AppController.h"

@implementation AppController
{
    NSNumber *_squareCount;
}
@synthesize squareView = _squareView;
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [_squareView setDelegate:nil];
    _squareCount = @(10);
    [_squareView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void)changeSquareCount:(id)sender
{
    _squareCount = @([sender intValue]);
    NSLog(@"square count stored: %@",_squareCount);
    [_squareView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
-(NSNumber *)numberOfSquaresInSquareView:(SquareView *) squareView
{
    NSLog(@"triggering numberOfSquaresInSquareView");
    return _squareCount;
}

@end
```

Comment: Where do you ever assign a non-nil value to the `delegate` property of a `SquareView` instance?

Comment: When you do `NSLog(@"squares to draw: %@", [delegate numberOfSquaresInSquareView:self]);`, what's the value of `delegate`. I guess it's `nil` since I only see this line setting it: `[_squareView setDelegate:nil];`. If it's nil, then there is no delegate object, so no-one to execute the delegate method, right? To illustrate, imagine having a manager (delegate) position, that's the delegate declaration (only a position, no hired people), employees that need that delegate. So the delegations won't work.

Comment: setNeedsDisplay belongs to NSView subclass, not to a controller. What you are trying to achieve is data source. Instead of calling setneedsdisplay you need method called reload. Look at how NSTableView is being implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `delegate` has to 'retain' somewhere to make it work. As I can see here, the `SquareView` is a sub-view of `AppController`, and the `delegate` works like `SquareView <-> AppController`. It's a kind of callback in this case. However, you're assigning it to `nil` by `[_squareView setDelegate:nil]` It should be:

```objectivec
_squareView.delegate = self;
```

By doing that, every time `drawRect` in SquareView gets called, it will trigger `numberOfSquaresInSquareView` in AppController, and in this case, it will print out

> squares to draw: 10